# Thumbnail of Videos not loading on Server | Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I am fairly new to Django and currently I'm making a Youtube Clone to understand Django in depth. So the problem I'm facing right now is that I can't seem to get the thumbnail to appear in homepage when I run the server. I've spent a lot of time trying but can't seem to find an answer! I'll provide what I think relates to my problem;

**1) Templates**

homeview.html:

```
`{% block body %}
{% for video in most_recent_video %}
<div class="video-card">
  <img src="/get_thumbnail/{{ video.thumbnail.path }}" alt="{{ video.title }} thumbnail">
  <h5>{{ video.title }}</h5>
  <p>Uploaded By {{ video.user }} on {{ video.datetime }}</p>
  <p>{{ video.description }}</p>
  <p><a href="/video/{{ video.id }}">Watch Video</a></p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}`
```

thumbnail.html:

```
`{% block body %}

    <div class="header-bar">
        <h2>Thumbnail View</h2>
        <hr>
    </div>

    <div class="main-body">
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table>
                {{ form.as_p }}
            </table>
            <button type="submit">Upload Thumbnail</button>
        </form>
        
        {% if errors %}
            <div class="errors">
                <h3>Errors:</h3>
                <ul>
                    {% for field_errors in errors.values %}
                        {% for error in field_errors %}
                            <li>{{ error }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>

{% endblock %}`
```

**2) views.py**

```
`class ThumbnailView(View):
    template_name = 'base/thumbnail.html'

    def get(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')

        form = ThumbNailForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = ThumbNailForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            # Create a new Thumbnail entry
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            thumbnail_file = form.cleaned_data['file']

            # Generate a random filename for the thumbnail
            random_chars = ''.join(random.choices(
                string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=10))
            filename = random_chars + thumbnail_file.name

            # Save the thumbnail file
            BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
            thumbnail_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, filename)
            with open(thumbnail_path, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(thumbnail_file.read())

            thumbnail = Thumbnail(title=title, path=filename)
            thumbnail.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
        else:
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'errors': form.errors})

class ThumbnailFileView(View):

    def get(self, request, file_name):
        BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
        stripped_file_name = file_name[10:] 
        file = FileWrapper(open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, stripped_file_name), 'rb'))
        response = HttpResponse(file, content_type='image/jpg')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}'.format(stripped_file_name)
        return response`
```

**3) urls.py**

```
   `path('get_thumbnail/<file_name>', ThumbnailFileView.as_view(), name='getthumbnail'),
    path('thumbnail/', ThumbnailView.as_view(), name='thumbnail'),`
```

**4) models.py**

```
`class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True ,blank=False, null=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dislikes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
class Thumbnail(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     path = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ThumbnailView(models.Model):
     image = models.ForeignKey(Video, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='thumbnails')`
```

**5) forms.py**

```
`class ThumbNailForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label='Title', max_length=50)
    file = forms.FileField()`
```

[**This is how it looks when I run server**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRxeL.png)

**6) Error on Console**

```
`<QuerySet [<Video: Video object (43)>, <Video: Video object (42)>, <Video: Video object (41)>, <Video: Video object (40)>, <Video: Video object (39)>, <Video: Video object (38)>, <Video: Video object (37)>, <Video: Video object (36)>, <Video: Video object (35)>]>
[01/Apr/2023 15:44:21] "GET /home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16180
Not Found: /get_thumbnail/
[01/Apr/2023 15:44:21] "GET /get_thumbnail/ HTTP/1.1" 404 13168`
```

**7) Path to image**

```
`
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Youtube Redesign\Config\img1.jpg
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Youtube Redesign\Config\img2.jpg
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Youtube Redesign\Config\img3.jpg`
```

I have been trying various things but can't seem to make it work!!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could edit your `Video` model in `views.py`.
You should add a `thumbnail` to your `Video` model to reference it in `homeview.html`.
Note that the other model fields work well in `homeview.html`

```
import PIL

class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True ,blank=False, null=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dislikes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

When you add `thumbnail` to the `Video` model, you replace the `src` value in the image tag with `{{ video.thumbnail.url }}`.

Your `homeview.html` should look like this.

```
{% block body %}
{% for video in most_recent_video %}
<div class="video-card">
  <img src="{{ video.thumbnail.url }}" alt="{{ video.title }} thumbnail">
  <h5>{{ video.title }}</h5>
  <p>Uploaded By {{ video.user }} on {{ video.datetime }}</p>
  <p>{{ video.description }}</p>
  <p><a href="/video/{{ video.id }}">Watch Video</a></p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```